# My corectrl installation isnt working, ive tried everything i know

Tags: linux, debian, failed-installation, chromebook

For an hour straight, ive been looking for solutions to install Corectrl but i just cant figure it out. I'd reached a roadblock when it told me this.

```
sudo apt install corectrl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 corectrl : Depends: libbotan-2-19 (>= 2.19.3+dfsg) but it is not installable
            Depends: libc6 (>= 2.38) but 2.31-13+deb11u7 is to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 13.1) but 10.2.1-6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

. Please help, thank you. If you need more info to help I can give more.

I tried using these,
`https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl`
`https://launchpad.net/~ernstp/+archive/ubuntu/mesarc`
and also these lines of code
`sudo apt-get -f install`
`sudo apt install aptitude     sudo aptitude install corectrl`
I have no idea why aptitude didnt work, maybe because i have a uninstallable dependancy
`sudo apt-get update`
This is everything I tried without the extras that are not relevant or now nonrelevant. (because I found out how to solve it using those lines of code).

Comment: Questions about package installation are out of scope for this venue.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

if your package get broken you may try this command.

apt --fix-broken install

and I see
libbotan-2-19, libc6, libstdc++6

those files come with system if you did delete these files or it's getting older you may update your linux distribution with basic command

sudo apt-get update

if you need to check upgradable list in your distribution.
use this command

apt list —upgradable

isn't work try recovery mode to recover your packages